# I don't know why SVM decision_function and predict_proba have different results

Tags: python, scikit-learn, cross-validation

```
clf = SVC(kernel = 'rbf', probability=True)
cv = KFold(n_splits=5, shuffle = False)

for train_index, test_index in cv.split(data[name][:, :]):
    X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = data[name][train_index], data[name][test_index], labels[train_index], labels[test_index]
    clf.fit(X_train, y_train)
    print('\ndecision_function : \n', clf.decision_function(X_test))
    print('\npredict probabilty : \n', clf.predict_proba(X_test)[:,1]) 
    print('prediction : ', clf.predict(X_test))


scores_temp = cross_val_score(clf, data[name], labels, cv = cv)
y_pred = cross_val_predict(clf, data[name], labels, cv=cv)
cfm = confusion_matrix(labels, y_pred, labels = [1,0])
print('cross_val_score : ', scores_temp)
print('y_pred :', y_pred)
```

I am conducting a binary classification of 20 data consisting of 23 features.

I use sklearn's SVM to perform 5fold-cross-validation, and both cross_val_score function and decision function methods produce the same results, but for the required predict_proba, my output produce different results.

When I set the threshold(default) to zero in the decision function, my output trying to produce the classification result that I want, but I wonder why clf.predict_proba has a higher probability of other classes (some data cases are printed correctly).

```
decision_function : 
 [-0.47648561 -1.10368407 -0.87143091  0.15767618]

predict probabilty : 
 [0.44280357 0.37062859 0.396561   0.51976092]
prediction :  [0 0 0 1]

decision_function : 
 [ 0.32952592 -0.40706183  0.75996465 -0.03300075]

predict probabilty : 
 [0.5 0.5 0.5 0.5]
prediction :  [1 0 1 0]

decision_function : 
 [-0.64538296 -0.17156661  0.19868302 -0.01625615]

predict probabilty : 
 [0.57873957 0.50805464 0.45274971 0.48478674]
prediction :  [0 0 1 0]

decision_function : 
 [-0.07399867 -0.24230866  0.07278593  0.4155084 ]

predict probabilty : 
 [0.52367709 0.48493753 0.55733607 0.63592478]
prediction :  [0 0 1 1]

decision_function : 
 [-0.30797883 -0.1165149   0.35051264 -0.0306706 ]

predict probabilty : 
 [0.48693078 0.5        0.53308813 0.50638279]
prediction :  [0 0 1 0]
cross_val_score :  [0.75 0.5  0.75 1.   0.75]
y_pred : [0 0 0 1 1 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 1 0]
```

Comment: You said that you are doing a binary classification. Then, why you have 4 possible classes when predicting the probabilities? Moreover, if you only have 20 sample and 23 features, your model won't be good at all. You should have more data.

Comment: There are 4 data that corresponds to class 1, not class. I
This is the case when print is carried out by proceeding with print_proba[:, 1]